# Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected type 'Query', but it was: a custom wh object

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am using angular and firebase 12.5.4. When I want to do a get I get the error

```
constructor(private auth: Auth, private firestore: Firestore) { 

    
  }

async getSelecciones()//:Promise<Observable<seleccion[]>>
  {    

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(this.firestore, "selecciones"));
    
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
   
  }
```

I'm trying to do a get from firestore